# Easy_Install in Python3 says setuptools not found even when it's up to date

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x, python-3.4

I ran "sudo easy_install3 py-notify" and had my setuptools updated to the current version (15), all my stuff is updated and upgraded. I don't understand why it can't detect setuptools.

It says I need 3.3
But I have 15, so how is it not working

```
$ sudo easy_install3 py-notify
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools-15.0-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 639, in _build_master
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools-15.0-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 940, in require
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools-15.0-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 832, in resolve
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (setuptools 15.0 (/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools-15.0-py3.4.egg), Requirement.parse('setuptools==3.3'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install3", line 5, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2214, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2203, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools-15.0-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3057, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools-15.0-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 641, in _build_master
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools-15.0-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 654, in _build_from_requirements
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools-15.0-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 827, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'setuptools==3.3' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Comment: Not sure. If you can, consider switching to `pip`. `easy_install` should no longer be used as it's outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have pip you can use: `pip list` to see all installed modules. if you can't see setuptools, install it manually.